# Applying htaccess directives to certain requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

On a Codeigniter application I want to limit http post request size (in bytes) with **limitRequestBody** htaccess directive. Since all requests are written to index.php this setting affects to all form submissions. That is problematic. What I really want is limit post size to certain urls. For example, if I have two urls, like below

1. mysite.com/member/login
2. mysite.com/contact

I only want to apply this setting only to the mysite.com/member/login. Not for mysite.com/contact

I tried with apache's LocationMatch and IF Directives to specifically target the url but unfortunately none of it worked. Instead server went into a redirect loop.

```
<LocationMatch "^/member/login">
      limitRequestBody 128
</LocationMatch>


<If "%{REQUEST_URI} ^/member/login">
      limitRequestBody 128
</If>
```

Is there anything wrong with the above approach? Syntax? or any other way to get this done?